# Отправляю данные на форму python-скриптом, получаю код 200, но ожидаемого письма нет

Tags: python, django

Проблема следующая: не могу отправить в форму на сайте данные через python-скрипт. Обычная форма обратной связи, которая исправно работает при ручном заполнении, но ничего не отправляет, если отсылать post-запрос скриптом. Что делать?
Вот необходимые коды.

**Cкрипт отправки запроса на сайт:**

```
import requests
import sys

URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
client = requests.session()
client.get(URL)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']

login_data = dict(lastname='Игин', name='Anton', middlename='Konst', birthday='2017-04-20', telephone='(896) 097-29-02', csrfmiddlewaretoken=csrftoken, next='form_call/')
r = client.post(URL, data=login_data, headers=dict(Referer=URL))
```

**views.py**

```
def form_call(request):
    if request.method=='POST':
        form = Call_Form(request.POST)
        name = request.POST.get('name', '')
        lastname = request.POST.get('lastname', '')
        middlename = request.POST.get('middlename', '')
        birthday = request.POST.get('birthday', '')
        telephone = request.POST.get('telephone', '')
        if form.is_valid():
            mail_host = SMTPMail.objects.all()[0] 
            rec_list = RecMail.objects.all()
            recipients= []
            for mail in rec_list:
                recipients.append(mail.mail) #Список получателей
            message = '''
                На сайте вашей структуры NL International появилась новая заявка на звонок! Вот данные, предоставленные новым консультантом:
                ФИО:{0} {1} {2}
                Дата рождения: {3}
                Телефон: {4}'''.format(name,lastname, middlename, birthday, telephone)
            subject= 'Заявка на звонок'
            send_mail(subject, message, mail_host.mail, recipients, fail_silently=False)
            return redirect('/thanks/')
        else:
            return redirect('/error/')
```

Comment: Приведите скрипт, который на фронте обрабатывает Ваш запрос.

Comment: `django-admin sendtestemail` работает-то?